# Raise exception when TCP connection broken

Tags: ruby, tcp

I'm building a server which accepts connections through TCP (using TCPServer). I mostly just read data (`socket.gets.chomp`) and write data (`socket.print`).

`socket.gets` will return `nil` if the connection has been closed by the client in the meantime, so `.chomp` will raise `NoMethodError`. This is hard to handle specifically since it's such an unspecific exception - I want to distinguish exceptions caused by the connection loss from other causes of `NoMethodError`, such as me typoing a method.

Ideally, I would receive something more specific such as `SocketError` whenever trying to interact with a closed socket, rather than just getting back `nil`. How could I accomplish that?

I have already considered these options:

- Write a wrapper for `TCPSocket` or `IO` which checks on socket availability before every call (a lot of work to do cleanly considering how many methods there are in `IO`)
- Check each return value for `nil` (even more effort and code redundancy as my application grows, also I would still `.print` to the socket when it's already closed)
- Monkey patching `NilClass` for `chomp` (again only handles this specific use case, and monkey patching should be avoided for clean code)

Comment: Monkey patching `NilClass` seems like the YOLO option here, best avoided. Why not `socket.gets&.chomp`?

Answer (score 0):

Being at end of file is not intrinsically an error, nor is it normally understood to mean a "broken" connection like your title says.

For example, HTTP allows multiple requests to be sent over a single connection. After completely reading a request you can read again, and if the connection is closed you'd get `nil`, which tells you there are no more requests coming. This situation isn't considered an error condition by most/all HTTP software.

Most Ruby software handles `nil` return from `read` as an indication that the network conversation is over (successfully). I suggest you do something like that.

If you wish to consider EOF an error, you could create a wrapper class for IO that would "upgrade" `nil` return from `read` into an exception of some kind, but I would suggest rethinking whether this is really what you need.

See also https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/IO.html#method-i-read.

Comment: In any case, `nil` means the connection is no longer available. I need to catch that case, whenever it happens during communication, such that I can gracefully handle it. Checking for `nil` on every call seems too much work; I'm asking for alternatives. How would I upgrade nil to an exception automatically?

Comment: I consider `nil` exceptional/broken since normally I'd know when the communication is over and the client is no longer expected to listen/respond, so if the client follows the protocol, the case of `nil` would never happen; it can only happen from unexpected connection termination by the client.

Comment: You want a non-usual behavior. You can get it by writing your own wrapper around standard library IO class, but the standard library doesn't provide it out of the box.